# Spring extension problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

If we stretch a spring by a force f at both ends and assuming each side extends by x then the total extension in the spring is x or 2x? because while solving problems in which two equal forces are applied we take the extension as x and not 2x.. plz explain why?

Comment: You will have to provide specific example of the problem. The answer to your first question is that yes the total extension is $2x$ if each side has extension of $x$. In the problems you are speaking of, they label the '$2x$' itself as '$x$'.

Comment: As @KalpakGupta mentions, you should quote the precise wording of the problem that confuses you. I don't think such question would ever say something like "each side extends". That would indeed be ambiguous. Question texts are in general always clear on that from my experience.

Answer (score 3):

I understand your confusion.   Here's the explanation:

If a force $F$ is said to be applied to a spring, it's *always* applied at both ends.    You can't apply a force to only one end of a spring, just as you can't apply a tension force to only one end of a rope.    So if you put a spring on a table and apply a force, $F$, the resulting extension of the spring will be given by
$$x = F/k,$$
since $F=kx$ for any spring.  You can hold one end still and make the $x$ be distributed as $x$ at the other end, or move the ends equally by $x/2$ at each end.    So it is incorrect to assume that a spring extends by $x$ on both sides when you are told that a force $F$ is applied.    If you have a spring on a table and actually make it extend by $x$ at both ends, then the force you have to apply will be $2F$ when compared to the first case.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't some opposing force at both ends of the spring the entire spring will accelerate. Determine the total difference in the forces experienced at each end (or tension) and use that to calculate extension.

Answer (score 0):

When diagrams of springs are drawn they often are fied at one end and only one force is shown be be acting at the free end of the spring.
If that was the only force acting on the spring then the spring would accelerate in the direction of the force.

The complete force diagram for a spring should shown an equal in magnitude but opposite in direction force acting on the spring at its fixed end.
This means that the net force on the spring is zero and so the spring is in static equilibrium.

If one applies a force $F$ on the free end of the spring the extension of the spring is given by $kx$ not $k2x$
If the force at the free end in increased the force at the fixed end is increased by exactly the same amount.

Perhaps you doubt is because there are two forces $F$ acting on the spring and you are adding them up to give $2F$?
That is a mistake because the two forces acting on the spring add up to a net force of zero $\vec F + (-\vec F) = 0$

**Update**

When investigating how the extension $x$ of a spring behaves with varying load $F$ one does the following:

[image]

The result is something like $F = kx$ where $k$ is the spring constant.

Drawing free body diagrams of the apparatus results in the following:

[image]

Note that there are two forces, magnitude $F$, acting on the spring but the extension is still $x$.

If the force due to the support was not there you could not extend the spring.

Comment: Does that mean when we apply equal forces on both ends the net extension is zero?? Your last equation F+(-F)=0 tells so.

Comment: My last equation is about the net force on the spring being zero so the spring does not accelerate.  However this two forces acting on the spring extend it.  The force $F$ in the equation $F=kx$ is the magnitude of one of the forces.

Comment: So if we apply the Forces F on both sides and assuming one end is extended by x then is the net extension in the spring 2x? Plz tell using equations where I am wrong..

Comment: @AdityaPandey I have updated my answer to show that the extension is still $x$ and **not** $2x$ even though there are two forces of magnitude $F$ acting on the spring.